# Firefox connectivity in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I have automated tests with Selenium and Firefox.
They run ok in a Docker environment.

Now, I'm switching to Kubernetes, and it works sometimes.  About 50% I have connectivity issues between Firefox and the web server I'd like to test.
They are in different pods.
The pod where Firefox is running does have connectivity with `curl` with the web server, but Firefox cannot communicate well.

Sometimes it connects partially, for example it doesn't download CSS.

Is there some Firefox DNS setting that I have to tune?

Here is an excerpt of the settings of pod that is running Firefox:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: blablabla
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      hostAliases:
        - ip: "10.17.18.112"
          hostnames:
            - myserver.mydomain.com
      containers:
         ....
```

I provide the IP (10.17.18.112) of the service that connects to the pod that hosts the web server.

I think DNS over https isn't activated in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It was a matter of the web server being too throtled in CPU.

With low parallelism in tests, no problem, but as the number of parallel tests increases, the web serverr cannot server in time the requests and Firefox fails.

I've increased the `resources.requests.cpu` value.